# How can I achieve the 2 second long click listing on day in v-calendar for vue js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vcalendar

Below is my code.

```
<script>
function dayClicked(day) {
    console.log(day, 'day');
}
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <v-calendar is-expanded show-weeknumbers is-range @dayclick='dayClicked' />
  </div>
</template>
```

It is working fine to get a click event on the day.
But I need to listen to the event for the long click of 2 seconds on a particular day.

So is there any way to achieve this thing in v-calendar or any other way?

**Packages detail for the specific version**

1. "vue": "^3.2.37"
2. "v-calendar": "^3.0.0-alpha.8",

Comment: Consider providing a *runnable* [mcve]. We have no way of knowing what vue and vcalendar versions you're using. Note codesandbox allows [importing](https://codesandbox.io/docs/learn/getting-started/your-first-sandbox#import-local-projects-via-cli) a local project using their CLI utility.

Comment: @tao I am using this packages  1. "vue": "^3.2.37"
 2. "v-calendar": "^3.0.0-alpha.8",

Comment: @tao Please answer the question if you know.

Comment: For a proper answer, your question needs a *runnable* example. What I mean is that adding this custom functionality needs testing. Anyone answering it would need to create their own, if you don't. Basically, you are: ***a)*** declaring your time is more valuable than the time of anyone helping you; ***b)*** increasing the risk the example made in the answer might not work in your project. If you expect me to answer your question in its current form, you ***will*** be disappointed. In principle I know what needs to be done to achieve it. If you prefer, I can write down the steps so you try it.